# Android best practices - How to Register multiple receivers for the same intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am working on an application where I am listening for multiple Android system level broadcast. Lets take BOOT_COMPLETED as an example.

```
<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now lets suppose I want another receiver to also listen in on `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent to do other work. Is it good practice to create another receiver to listen to the same thing in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiverAnotherOne">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

or should I design the code such that `StartupReceiver` is the only one listening to a single intent.

So basically my question I think if I can rephrase it correctly is whether its good practice for multiple broadcast receivers to listen on the same intent? Are there any problems with this approach? Is there any Android guideline that says not to do this or they don't suggest doing this? OR is this totally valid?

Comment: For the same event I would start one receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` of your `BroadcastReceiver` you can check from where (from which activity) the `Intent` has come from.To do this use something like

```
public class BroadcastListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.your.package.YourActivity")) {
            //do something
        }

   else if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.your.package.YourAnotherActivity"))     {
        //do something else    
        }
    }
}
```

So i don't think it's needed to use multiple `BroadcastReceivers` to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Sash_KP didnt understood what the user Jarod asked.

I do believe that all alternatives will work, a system where each receiver is written alone, or a system where each receiver is grouped.

There is no practical difference, as each register works independant.
To answer briefly:

Its easier to read and do maintenance on a system where each receiver is alone.

But if several different broadcasts starts the same Activity/Service, then its better to have that register all of its conditions.